# mypy infers unexpected Arg in python type signature

Tags: python, type-inference, mypy, python-typing

I am currently introducing type hints into a project I am currently working at.
To check the type signatures, I am using the `mypy` type checker.

When using the `map` function, I am getting unexpected error messages about the type of the function being unexpected:
The type signature inferred by `mypy` contains an additional `Arg(..., 'C')` ('C' being the parameter name) wrapping the type I expected to see in this position.

This seems to be specific to `set`, as this doesn't happen with `frozenset`s.

The code below is a minimal example showcasing the odd behavior I'm observing:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, Iterable, Iterator, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class OwnIterable(Generic[T]):
    T = TypeVar("T")

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[set[T]]:
        return [].__iter__()

class DemoClass(Generic[T]):

    def __call__(self, P: OwnIterable[T]) -> float:

        def inner_fun(C: set[T]) -> float:
            return 42.0

        def inner_fun_frozen(C: frozenset[T]) -> float:
            return 42.0

        ## The following line of code causes mypy to yield the following error:
        ##   error: Argument 1 to "map" has incompatible type "Callable[[Arg(Set[T], 'C')], float]"; expected "Callable[[Set[T]], float]"  [arg-type]
        map_obj = map(inner_fun, P)
        a = sum(map_obj)

        ## Weirdly, when using inner_fun_frozen, mypy gives the following error:
        ##   error: Argument 1 to "map" has incompatible type "Callable[[FrozenSet[T]], float]"; expected "Callable[[Set[T]], float]"  [arg-type]
        ## The emphasis here is on the fact that the type signature contains `FrozenSet[T]` directly, rather than wrapped in an `Arg(..., 'C')`!
        map_obj_frozen = map(inner_fun_frozen, P)
        b = sum(map_obj_frozen)

        ## Moreover, when the code from the first example line is not split over two lines, mypy yields the *two* errors below, i.e. one additional error:
        ##   error: Argument 1 to "map" has incompatible type "Callable[[Arg(Set[T], 'C')], float]"; expected "Callable[[Set[T]], float]"  [arg-type]
        ##   error: Argument 1 to "map" has incompatible type "Callable[[Set[T]], float]"; expected "Callable[[Set[T]], bool]"  [arg-type]
        c = sum(map(inner_fun, P))

        return a + b + c
```

I'd also like to know why mypy would expect `Callable[[Set[T]], bool]` when the statement is not split over multiple lines (as shown in the third example).

Is this a misunderstanding on my part of how the type inference is working?

Comment: Remove `T = TypeVar("T")` from `OwnIterable` class body, it shouldn't be there. After that, only `frozenset` remains prohibited as expected (because `frozenset` isn't a `set` subtype, which can be validated by running mypy on `x: frozenset[str] = {'a'}`). https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=b7ec950b2cad55591df4726d70f72426

Comment: Thank you for the response! Yes, this seems to correspond to the superfluous `TypeVar` in `OwnIterable`. I'd really like to know though where the "named argument" (?) in the type comes from and why it seems to only happen for `set` and not for other classes.